# Как выдернуть из JSON значения?

Tags: c#, json, winforms

Добрый день.

Подскажите как правильно спарсить часть значений из подобного JSON кода:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "params": [
      {
        "n": "Вид оборудования",
        "s": false,
        "t": "s",
        "r": true,
        "e": null,
        "l": [],
        "v": {
          "_5115": {
            "n": "Для магазина",
            "id": "5115"
          },
          "_5116": {
            "n": "Для офиса",
            "id": "5116"
          },
          "_5117": {
            "n": "Для ресторана",
            "id": "5117"
          },
          "_5118": {
            "n": "Для салона красоты",
            "id": "5118"
          },
          "_5119": {
            "n": "Промышленное",
            "id": "5119"
          },
          "_795": {
            "n": "Другое",
            "id": "795"
          }
        },
        "id": "181"
      }
    ],
    "photos": "5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Пример его использования [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401756/parsing-json-using-json-net).

Answer (score 6):

[Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Работает быстрее стандартного сериализатора, имеет дофига полезных фич, которых в стандартном сериализаторе нет.

Answer (score 3):

Юзаю вот эту, доволен как слон) Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Это и есть Json.NET

Comment: Прошу прощения, не знал, знаю по имени dll и спецификации)